# How can I prevent Python while loop from pausing each time the plot is generated until plot is closed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on learning APIs and trying to do a live plot of weather data sampled every few minutes. I imagine the plot should be created outside of the while loop and then updated within the loop, but I cannot initialize it without any data. How can I make the plot persistent & update with each loop without having to close the plot to continue to next loop?

```
plotdata = []

while True:
    response = requests.get(f"{url}q={q}&units={units}&appid={apikey}")
    obj = response.json()
    temp = obj["main"]["temp"]
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f"Current temperature in Chicago at {current_time}: {temp}")
    plotdata.append((current_time, temp))
    plt.scatter(*zip(*plotdata))
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I assume you are using matplotlib or something. Look up interactive mode: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion

Comment: Yes, matplotlib. It looks I may need to use [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) from Animation class, which calls a function for each frame. I can have the waiting time built in to the frame time, and call the API for each new frame. I will report later if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified to the following, which instead uses FuncAnimation. Works correctly now.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []

def animate(i, xs, ys):
    response = requests.get(f"{url}q={q}&units={units}&appid={apikey}")
    obj = response.json()
    temp = obj["main"]["temp"]
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f"Current temperature in Chicago at {current_time}: {temp}")
    xs.append(current_time)
    ys.append(temp)
    xs = xs[-20:]
    ys = ys[-20:]
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(xs, ys)
    # plt.draw()
    # time.sleep(2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=300000)
plt.show()
```